# Determine alphanumeric pattern in string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is script for a simplified version of the df in question:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
               'reg': ['AAA123', '456BBB','C7C8C9','DDDEEE01010']
                 })
df

    reg
0   AAA123
1   456BBB
2   C7C8C9
3   DDDEEE01010
```

I would like to create a column which represents the alphanumeric pattern of each reg value, with an `'L'` for each letter and `'N'` for each number.

Please note that the reg can vary in length and have a random number and order of letters and numbers.

INTENDED OUTPUT:

```
    reg          pattern
0   AAA123       LLLNNN
1   456BBB       NNNLLL
2   C7C8C9       LNLNLN
3   DDDEEE01010  LLLLLLNNNNN
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace` with `regex` option:

```
df['pattern'] = df.reg.replace({'[a-zA-Z]':'L', '\d':'N'}, regex=True)
```

Or if you are certain that your string contains only alphanumeric character, you can use `\D` for alpha:

```
    df['pattern'] = df.reg.replace({'\D':'L', '\d':'N'}, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
           reg      pattern
0       AAA123       LLLNNN
1       456BBB       NNNLLL
2       C7C8C9       LNLNLN
3  DDDEEE01010  LLLLLLNNNNN
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's `.replace`, not `.str.replace`. `.replace` allows passing of dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Using `str.replace` we can try:

```
data["pattern"] = data["reg"].str.replace(r'[A-Z]', 'L')
                             .str.replace(r'[0-9]', 'N')
```